# Python Pandas, remove increasing rows of a column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, rows

Here's the short example version of my problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.arange(1, 101, 1)
y1 = np.linspace(0, 1000, 50)
y2 = np.linspace(500, 2000, 50)
y = np.concatenate((y1, y2))
data = np.asmatrix([x, y]).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax.plot(df.iloc[:, 0], df.iloc[:, 1], 'r')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

Please run the code and see the plot it generates.[image]

I want to read the dataframe from the back (from x=100 to x=0) and make sure my y-axis is always decreasing (from y=2000 to y=0). I want to remove rows where the y value is not decreasing when read from the end of the dataframe.

How can I edit my dataframe to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really happy with this solution, but it's better than nothing. I found it really hard to describe this problem without becoming too vague. Please comment if you see room for improvement, because I know there is.

```
newindex = []
max = -999

for row in df.index:
    if df.loc[row, 1] > max:
        max = df.loc[row, 1]
        newindex.append(row)

df = df.loc[newindex,]
```